# How to set orthgraphic matrix for a 2d camera with zooming?

Tags: c++, 2d, camera, directx9

I'm using ID3DXSprite to draw my sprites and haven't set any kind of camera projection matrix. How to setup an orthographic projection matrix for camera in DirectX which it would be able to support zoom functionality?

```
    D3DXMATRIX orthographicMatrix;
    D3DXMATRIX identityMatrix;

    D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&orthographicMatrix, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&identityMatrix);

    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &orthographicMatrix);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &identityMatrix);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &identityMatrix);
```

This code is for initial setup. Then, for zooming I multiply zoom factor in `nScreenWidth` and `nScreenHeight`.

**UPDATE**

This is going to work:

```
    D3DXMATRIX orthographicMatrix;
    D3DXMATRIX identityMatrix;
    D3DXMATRIX viewMatrix = D3DXMATRIX(
        1,      0,      0,      0,
        0,      1,      0,      0,
        0,      0,      1,      0,
        (FLOAT)(-(this->nScreenWidth / 2)), (FLOAT)(-(this->nScreenHeight / 2)),        0,      1
    );

    D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&orthographicMatrix, (FLOAT)this->nScreenWidth, (FLOAT)-this->nScreenHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&identityMatrix);

    this->p_device->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &orthographicMatrix);
    this->p_device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &identityMatrix);
    this->p_device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &viewMatrix);
```

And put `D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE` flag next to other flags when you use `ID3DXSprite::Begin()`:

```
if(this->p_sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND | ... | D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE) != D3D_OK) return 0;
```

For zoom functionality you can produce this matrix:

```
D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&orthographicMatrix, this->nScreenWidth * this->dZoom, -this->nScreenHeight * this->dZoom, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Typically you wouldn't scale each object, but you would instead change your perspective of the scene. That's done with the camera object. There shouldn't be any need to touch any of the objects in the world when zooming.

Comment: Currently I'm applying a zoom factor multiplied in each object's scale factor to set sizes for my scaling matrix. I'm using ID3DXSprite to achieve this and I don't know how to change my perspective as you've mentioned. I'm not using orthographic view in my rendering pipeline. At least I don't remember that I've set something like this or not because there is none.

Comment: @Byte56, Thanks for the advice. I'll go for it.

Comment: @MahanGM If you haven't set a projection matrix then you're just implicitly using the identity matrix for projection.  A simple way to zoom would be to just use an XY scaling matrix for the projection, rather than scaling every individual sprite and associated Box2D body.  Presumably you need to do something similar for translation, unless you want to reset the position of every Box2D body when you move the camera.

Comment: @NathanReed, Thank you for `identity matrix` reminder. I'll go look for some information about setting camera in DirectX.

Comment: I don't really see a question about how to properly implement a 2D camera zoom. If you want to edit this question to something about how to properly implement zoom with a 2D camera, it would probably work better. And Nathan can provide an answer.

Comment: @Byte56 I didn't know how to express my question so I did what I could. I'd go for an edit to prevent future misunderstandings by Googlers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned `ID3DXSprite`, I assume you're using Direct3D 9.  In that case, you can set the projection matrix using

```
pDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, projMatrix);
```

The `projMatrix` for a 2D camera with zooming and translation could be constructed as follows:

```
s     0     0  0
0     s     0  0
0     0     1  0
-x*s  -y*s  0  1
```

where `x, y` is the camera position and `s` is the zoom factor.
This is the result of a translation by `-x, -y` (centering the view on the camera position) followed by a 2D scale by `s`.

Comment: How about using `D3DXMatrixOrthoLH`? Take a look at my code. If that's not going to work just say yep, and I'm going to use your matrix.

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happened.

Comment: @MahanGM Sure, `D3DXMatrixOrthoLH` should work (although it doesn't include translation).  So the sprites don't zoom if you set the projection matrix before drawing the sprites?  I wonder if `ID3DXSprite` ignores the matrices set on the device for some reason.  You might try setting the matrix with `ID3DXSprite::SetTransform` instead and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: The thing is, `ID3DXSprite::SetTransform` would change each sprite's perspective not the camera's. And currently I'm using `D3DXMatrixTransformation2D` to produce that matrix. I might go on using textured quads. Thanks for indications.

Comment: @MahanGM Ahh, I looked at the docs again and found that you need to add the `D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE` flag when calling `ID3DXSprite::Begin`.  Otherwise it indeed ignores the device world/view/projection matrices.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But now I'm getting an upside down scene and there is only the second half of screen visible to me. I used `D3DXMatrixOrthoLH`, there is no difference with your matrix too.

Comment: I've got it working. Actually I set the matrix that you've provided, for `D3DTS_VIEW` transformation with a little bit of modification, and used `D3DXMatrixOrthoLH` for `D3DTS_PROJECTION`. Thank you for help.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I'm still getting an upside down presentation.

Comment: @MahanGM Try negating the Y axis scale.

Comment: Thanks man. I'll put a complete code of mine for future readers.